# Sending a binary stream with Sinatra 1.3

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm building a Sinatra app that needs to send files to the user that it has just downloaded from elsewhere (essentially a proxy).

Whilst I have the bulk of it working, I cannot get Sinatra to send the correct filename as specified in my code.  The code I'm using is:

```
get '/' do
  attachment file.name
  headers['Content-Type'] = file.content_type
  headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment'
  file.body
end
```

(`file.body` is the contents of the file)

How can I get Sinatra to use the filename I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment;filename=the_file.txt"
```